# Show More/Show Less ngFor data on button click

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am getting an issue while showing and hide ngFor data. I want to show one record by default and when anyone clicks on the See more button remaining record will be shown. I don't want to autoclose the prev records. Currently, the previous Itinerary content will be autoclosed when I open another itinerary. Anyone, please help me? Here is the components file.

```
<div class="itineraryDay" *ngFor="let eventList of eventDailyItineraray; let i = index">
<div class="itineraryDay-header">
    <h5>Day {{i+1}}</h5>
    <p>{{eventList.tourevents[0]?.categoryName}}</p>
</div>
<div class="itineraryDay-detail">
    <div class="itinerary-cards">
        <mat-card class="mycard" *ngFor="let event of eventList.tourevents | slice:0:[selectedIndex === i ? max  : 1 ]; let j = index">
            <div class="day-activity d-flex">
                <div class="activity-img">
                    <img [src]="(event?.eventPic ? firstEventImage(event?.itemId,event?.eventPic):'./assets/media/icons/preview-item.svg')" />
                </div>
                <div class="activity-detail">
                    <div class="activity-detail-inner d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        <div class="activity-category d-flex">
                            <img src="{{categoryPic}}{{event?.categoryIcon}}" />
                            <span>{{event?.itemName}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="activity-hours d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
                            <img src="./assets/media/icons/access_time-24px.svg" />
                            <span>{{durationCalculation(event?.duration)}} Hours</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p>{{event?.description}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
    <div class="see-more">
        <div class="icon-inner">
            <p (click)="toggle(i, $event)" class="seeMore">See More</p>
            <div class="more-icon" (click)="toggle(i, $event)" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedIndex === i}" >
                <i class="flaticon-eye"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the click function in ts file.

```
toggle(index, event){

this.max = this.eventDailyItineraray[index].tourevents.length;

if(this.selectedIndex === index){
  this.selectedIndex = -1;
  event.currentTarget.parentElement.children[0].innerText = 'See More';
}else{
  this.selectedIndex = index;
  event.currentTarget.parentElement.children[0].innerText = 'See Less';
} }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want mannage a list of items, so you need an array -not a single variable-. So defined an array

```
more:boolean[]=[]
```

futhermore, to change the text in the html NOT use something so "bizarro" as `event.currentTarget.parentElement.children[0].innerText = 'See More'`, better "angular way"

```
<p (click)="more[i]==!more[i]" class="seeMore">
    {{more[i]?'See Less':'See more'}}
</p>
```

And replace your

```
`selectedIndex === i` by `more[i]`
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I want to change the value of array slice (List of items) too on click of See More button. By default slice value is 0 and on click of See More button we need to show the remaining lists.  @Eliseo

Answer (score 0):

You can try put 'trackby' concept here. It will track previous changes and other changes will be added smoothly

```
<...*ngFor="let item of items; trackBy:trackByIdentity">
```

and inside your .ts file

```
trackByIdentity(index, item){
     return item.<attribute_which_is_unique>; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do in such cases (and it may be a "cheap" solution, but I couldn't come up with better ideas so far) is to add a value into each object inside your iterable, indicating if that item should have an active class or not. In your case, when you are fetching youeventList.tourevents, you could go map it and add something like (isActive = false) to each object inside, then bind that value to the class of each item in your ngFor loop.

So when you click on the toggle button, you pass the index of the ngFor item, and modify that value in your array - which should append or remove the active class name for your appropriate item, and won't do anything with the rest items in your ngFor loop. I hope it's clear, I may update my answer with example code if needed.

Comment: If we use this approach by adding/removing class, it will affect the page speed. if data are huge. @IamFlok

Comment: In case of huge data, shouldn't you optimize performance using inifnite-scroll or something similar? I also wonder if there are better ways of doing this. @Faizi

Comment: Did you use trackBy approach before? I am unable to achieve this thing by trackBy @IamFlok

Comment: In case of huge data, there are images with each record which will increase the page load time.@IamFlok

Comment: Could you please send me any example code which you were talking about? @IamFlok